# Why is memcpy with 16 byte twice as fast as memcpy with 1 byte?

Tags: c++, performance

I'm doing some performance measurements. When looking at memcpy, I found a curious effect with small byte sizes. In particular, the fastest byte count to use for my system is 16 bytes. Both smaller and larger sizes get slower. Here's a screenshot of my results from a larger test program.

[image]

I've minimized a complete program to reproduce the effect just for 1 and 16 bytes (note this is MSVC code to suppress inlining to prevent optimizer to nuke everything):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using dbl_ns = std::chrono::duration<double, std::nano>;

template<size_t n>
struct memcopy_perf {
   uint8_t m_source[n]{};
   uint8_t m_target[n]{};
   __declspec(noinline) auto f() -> void
   {
      constexpr int repeats = 50'000;
      const auto t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      for (int i = 0; i < repeats; ++i)
         std::memcpy(m_target, m_source, n);
      const auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      std::cout << "time per memcpy: " << dbl_ns(t1 - t0).count()/repeats << " ns\n";
   }
};

int main()
{
   memcopy_perf<1>{}.f();
   memcopy_perf<16>{}.f();

   return 0;
}
```

I would have hand-waved away a minimum at 8 bytes (maybe because of 16 bit on a 64 bit register size) or at 64 bytes (cache line size). But I'm somewhat puzzled at the 16 bytes. The effect is reproducible on my system and not a fluke.

Notes: I'm aware of the intricacies of performance measurements. Yes, this is in release mode. Yes, I made sure things are not optimized away. Yes, I'm aware there are libraries for this. Yes, n is too low, etc etc. This is a minimal example. I checked the asm, it calls memcpy.

Comment: amd64/x86-64 computers typically have a 128-bit memory bus.  (128 bits = 16 bytes).  That's how many bits can be moved together at a time.

Comment: huh! I need to read up on this. This is a Zen2 indeed. Thank you!

Comment: You should be measuring `time/byte` for larger copies. Also any modern compiler will ignore the loop and copy only once or not at all.

Comment: It's dual-channel 64-bit, technically. (Which is still effectively 128-bit).  Not to be confused with DDR (double data rate).  But yes, read up about motherboards and memory architectures!  :)

Comment: @Quimby I'm explicitly showing absolute times to drive home the fact that a smaller dataset takes less time - absolutely. Also obviously optimizer are crucial in any perf scenario. But as I wrote - I checked. When writing this specific way, MSVC does not optimize even multiple memcopies away.

Comment: please re-check your measurements https://godbolt.org/z/PPG7PaMYh and a different way https://godbolt.org/z/haob9oxjK

Comment: @Alexander I specifically mentioned MSVC and the inline declspec. WIthout either of them, stuff gets optimized away. I'm sure there is a way to make gcc run through the hoops, but I didn't do that. Also I don't think godbolt is a good perf tool.

Comment: @Alexander You should always run your test 10, 100, 1000, ... times to see if the measurement converges. In your case it would have shown that it gets faster the more repetitions you make showing that the loop gets optimized away. The compiler actually changes the code into `memset`.

Comment: Writing 1 byte needs to fetch the cache line and update that 1 byte. Anything below a cache line actually should. But on repetition the cache line will be already in cache so this is a very bad way to measure that effect. Then you have data that fits into a CPU register, MMX register, SSE register. Add to that alignment differences. You need to measure so much more than a call to `memcpy()` that the compiler eliminates.

Comment: @Wyck I disagree. The operation is done in at least the L1 cache regarding the speed of the operation for 16-bytes (eg. >100 GB/s). Zen2 does *not* operate on 128-bit wide memory read/store unlike Zen & Zen+. To quote [Wikichip](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_2): "Zen 2 can load and store 256-bit vectors in a single operation". The L2 transfers are also 256-bit wide.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that MSVC 19 is used since there is not information about the MSVC version yet.

The **benchmark is biased** so it cannot actually help to tell which one is faster, especially for such a small timing.

Indeed, here is the assembly code of MSVC 19 with `/O2` between the two calls to `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now`:

```
        mov     cl, BYTE PTR [esi]
        add     esp, 4
        mov     eax, 50000                                ; 0000c350H
        npad    6

$LL4@f:
        sub     eax, 1            <--- This is what you measure !
        jne     SHORT $LL4@f

        lea     eax, DWORD PTR _t1$[esp+20]
        mov     BYTE PTR [esi+1], cl
        push    eax
```

One can see that you measure a nearly empty loop that is completely useless and more than half the instructions are not the ones meant to be measured. The only useful instructions are certainly:

```
        mov     cl, BYTE PTR [esi]
        mov     BYTE PTR [esi+1], cl
```

Even assuming that the compiler could generate such a code, the call to `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now` certainly takes several dozens of nano seconds (since the usual solution to measure very small timing precisely is to use `RDTSC` and `RDTSCP`). This is far more than the time to execute such instruction. In fact, at such a granularity the notion of wall clock time vanishes. Instructions are typically executed in parallel in an out of order way and are also pipelined. At this scale one need to consider the latency of each instruction, their reciprocal throughput, their dependencies, etc.

An alternative solution is to reimplement the benchmark so the compiler cannot optimize this. But this is pretty hard to do since copying 1 byte is nearly free on modern x86 architectures (compared to the overhead of the related instructions needed to compute the addresses, loop, etc.).

AFAIK copying 1 byte on an AMD Zen2 processor has a reciprocal throughput of ~1 cycle (1 load + 1 store scheduled on both 2 load ports and 2 store ports) assuming data is in the L1 cache. The latency to read/write a value in the L1 cache is 4-5 cycles so the latency of the copy may be 8-10 cycles. For more information about this architecture please check [this](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_2).

Comment: Just no. I said that I checked. My asm is different, maybe it's VS22. And yes ofc now() takes a bit, that's why it's measuring 50 TOUSAND memcopies in between.

Comment: How are we suppose to know the assembly you have on your machine if you do not provide it? You do not provide the MSVC version either. You also do not provide optimization flags. Please provide more profiling information. Anyway even if the compiler do not optimize the accesses, the benchmark is still biased. Zen2 is an OOO superscalar processor and it execute instructions in parallel so you have to care about dependencies and latency between instruction. The actual instructions used are critical to know this!

Comment: You are not supposed to know. I wanted a high-level explanation and I got it. Since it was given as a comment I can't close this question, which will lead to more pointless quibbles.

Comment: Think: Your measurement is 0.12 ns to copy 16 bytes! Your processor cannot run at >8GHz, thus multiple blocks have to be copied per cycle. Since a copy cannot be done in 1 instruction on x86 architecture, 2 instructions are needed per item copied (read+write). Thus, 4 memory instructions per block code which is impossible on Zen2. Thus, assuming you are right about the asm code, there is a complex effect you did not consider. Really: can a processor copy a 16-bytes block **at the same location twice in one cycle**? You can analyse all of this scientifically, but would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to know is to check the resulting assembly. for example if 16 byte version is aligned on 16 then it uses aligned load/store operations and becomes faster than 4 byte / 1 byte version.

Maybe if it can not vectorize(use register) due to bad alignment, it falls back to do cache copy like mov operations on memory address instead of register.

Answer (score 0):

The `memcpy` implementation is depend on many factors, such as:

- OS: windows 10, linux, macos,...
- Compiler: GCC 4.4, GCC 8.5, CL, cywin-gcc, clang...
- CPU architecture: arm, arm64, x86, x86_64,....
- ...

So, with difference system, `memcpy` may have difference performance/behavior.
Example: SSE2, SSE3, AVX, AVX512 memcpy version be implmented on this system, but not on other system.

In your case, I think it's mainly caused by `memory alignment`. And with `1 byte` copy, the `un-alignment` memory access is always happen (more read/write cycle).